# How to prove that mod$((n-1)(n+1),n)=(n-1) $ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's obvious that the answer of the modulo-term = $(n-1)$ for $n>0$ but how can I prove that? First of all I thougt it would be easy with induction, but isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(n-1)(n+1)=n^2-1\equiv -1 \equiv n-1 \mod n$$